# What is the superscript number in Bitcoinica prices?

Tags: trading

Since [Bitcoinica](https://www.bitcoinica.com/) has been released I've been reading a bit about Forex. But i don't know what the superscript number refers to in the price quotes on the front page. How is this number calculated and what does it indicate? Or are they just simply pips?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These are indeed pips, according to [this comment](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=42267.msg553985#msg553985) by Bitcoinica's owner. That is, they are just an extra digit denoting multiplies of 0.00001 USD.